# Route match using GPS coordinates (Trace is not continuous)

Tags: routes, here-api

We have been using route matching using the following URL in order to do route match using GPS coordinates:
http://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json

This has been working normally.

During the recent days we found out that some requests submitted to the API return the following error:
{"faultCode":"461d67da-d9ff-4c1e-a6a1-4df9ed3f4322","responseCode":"400 Bad Request","message":"Trace is not continuous. Please submit each trace individually"}

I understand that the set of coordinates submitted are not continuous and we should do a small data preparation/filtering.
This could be easier if we knew what are the criterias from the data to be continuous.
Knowing this  we could properly clean the data and resubmit it.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our research, we found that there is a new fraud detection mechanism which is accidentally kicking in here.
We're going to fix it before end of July 2021.

Please let us know in case the issue pops up again after July.